# How can I test my chaincode in debug mode?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am using the 1.4 version of fabric, and I write a test in chaincode which imitated the Demo Chaincode "Commercial Paper".But when I deploy the chaincode in my Hyperledger Fabric Network, I found a error in `init`:

```
019-08-29T05:11:26.796Z error [shim:lib/handler.js] 
[arthurchannel3-6cfe6442] Calling chaincode Init() returned error response
[Error: object type or attribute not a non-zero length string]. 
Sending ERROR message back to peer
```

Can anyone help me with writing tests on chaincode?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to Debug chaincode (smart contracts) is to use the VS Code editor with the IBM Blockchain Platform extension.  This integrates the native VS Code debugger with the Fabric Peer dev-mode debugging.  There is a tutorial included in the extension for debugging.

If you do not wish to use the IBM extension with VS Code, there is documentation in the [Fabric Docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html#testing-using-dev-mode) about how to work with the samples using a peer in "dev mode".

The IBM extension for VS Code will also generate skeleton tests for you too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Hyperledger Fabric Debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Spydra.hyperledger-fabric-debugger) extension for Visual Studio code which supports both Go and Node.js chaincode debugging currently